# Magento layouts and templates using getChildHtml()

Tags: templates, layout, magento

I have looked quite a few Magento references, but still struggling to materialize how to solve this problem.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
                      <action method="setTemplate">
                          <template>ash_ajacart/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</template>
                      </action>
                      <block type="ajacart/product_view" name="wow" as="wow" template="ash_ajacart/ajacart-js.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Is my layout XML file.  The template "addtocart.phtml" renders fine.  But when I call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('wow') ?>` inside of that template it doesn't call the "ajacart-js.phtml" template.  I don't know if I am structuring everything wrong in the XML file, but it seems right to me.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `<block type="ajacart/product_view" name="wow" as="wow" template="ash_ajacart/ajacart-js.phtml" />` you must have a block class that matches `ajacart/product_view`. If not, the simplest way to get the template to show is change the `type` to `core/template`.

Comment: I do have a block that uses the class Block_Product_View, if that is what you're asking.